# Docker image tag is not working

Tags: docker

I have tried to build an image using centos as base and I did not specify the tag on the Dockerfile. The build is not appearing in the images. Some layers are in the images but not the final tag.

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile and also the build command you're using.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. If you don't specify the tag, the final image will not have any tags. However, you don't specify the tag in the Dockerfile. It will be be argument on the build command. Eg.

```
docker build -t centos:latest <url>
```

url could be an actual URL or any directory contains the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dockerfile and see the image creation logs. Your image is not built completely and aborts in the middle. 
Possible problem is sometimes you can forget the -y flag for installations in the dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *Dockerfile* to ensure that the `FROM` instruction does not specify the `latest` tag explicitly. If the FROM instruction is like FROM `base_image:latest`, it will inherit the "latest" tag from the base image. Which means `-t` won't take effect.